# How to draw an open arc in javafx?

Tags: javafx, automatic-ref-counting

I need to draw an open arc.

However, when I enter these values, for example:

```
Arc arc = new Arc();
arc.setCenterX(100.0f);
arc.setCenterY(100.0f);
arc.setRadiusX(80.0f);
arc.setRadiusY(80.0f);
arc.setStartAngle(0.0f);
arc.setLength(80.0f);
arc.setType(ArcType.OPEN);
```

so it will be displayed:

[image]

Why did not he just draw an arc? So how do I draw it?

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default fill is `Color.BLACK`.

You should set it to `Color.TRANSPARENT`

Adding `setStroke` and `setStrokeWidth` to make the arc visible.

like this:

```
arc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
arc.setStrokeWidth(2);
arc.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

[Look here:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#setFill-javafx.scene.paint.Paint-)

> `setFill`
>
> `public final void setFill(Paint value)`
>
> Sets the value of the property fill.
>
> **Property description:**
> Defines parameters to fill the interior of an Shape using the settings of the Paint context. The default value is Color.BLACK for all shapes except Line, Polyline, and Path. The default value is null for those shapes.

Comment: I believe OP will also need to set the `stroke` (and maybe `strokeWidth`). Just setting the `fill` to `TRANSPARENT` makes the `Arc` invisible (at least for me).

Comment: @Slaw Added to the answer.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Is it even possible to smooth the edges?

Comment: @MichalRama Do you mean like using `setSmooth(true)`?

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted.