# Trying to make a circle of different colours in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm awfully new to Javafx and want to try and make a very simple game. I'm trying to plot colors in a circle. The circle has different colors and must be hollow on the inside. I'll show a picture here:
[image]

I know I could just print out the image but I want to find out when the player collides with the incorrect color(exactly like how it is done in color switch) so that they lose in that case which I'm assuming wont be possible if i used the picture. How do i go about this?

Comment: I tried doing this but for some reason, it never shows up, I keep trying to add it to the scene but it just wont work, but say adding a circle or another button works.

Answer (score 1):

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FourArcs extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Arc arc = new Arc();
        arc.setCenterX(100.0f);
        arc.setCenterY(100.0f);
        arc.setRadiusX(80.0f);
        arc.setRadiusY(80.0f);
        arc.setStartAngle(0.0f);
        arc.setLength(90.0f);
        arc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        arc.setStrokeWidth(10);
        arc.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Arc arc2 = new Arc(100, 100, 80, 80, 90, 90);
        arc2.setStroke(Color.PURPLE);
        arc2.setStrokeWidth(10);
        arc2.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Arc arc3 = new Arc(100, 100, 80, 80, 180, 90);
        arc3.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
        arc3.setStrokeWidth(10);
        arc3.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Arc arc4 = new Arc(100, 100, 80, 80, 270, 90);
        arc4.setStroke(Color.RED);
        arc4.setStrokeWidth(10);
        arc4.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Group root = new Group(arc, arc2, arc3, arc4);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The above code is based on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54502045/how-to-draw-an-open-arc-in-javafx).

Screen capture:

[image: Screen capture.]

Comment: Alright, thanks! this worked well, don't get why it didn't work before but with a few shifts in my code and I've now got it.